# is there a way to display text from a file on a network machine on my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-application, windows-desktop-gadgets

The file I need is textfile.txt on a network share accessible from my machine. Is there any way to display this text on my windows 7 desktop using the least number of additional frameworks installed (assume everyone on the network who will use this app has .Net pre-installed). The contents of the file may change.

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

[Developing a Windows Sidebar Gadget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you a head start. You won't need any client side frameworks for the task at hand because every action you need to code can be done in JavaScript.

Comment: sorry, i was thinking more along the lines of a managed code app. this has to be possible. and yes, multiple people on the network will be using it.

Comment: @Freakishly Maybe you should rephrase your question because _least number of additional frameworks_ would exclude .NET as well.

Comment: @Freakishly Did give the MSDN sample implementation a try?